# Server-side pagination in mean stack application

Tags: mean-stack

I am working on mean stack application with angular 4.I am worrying about pagination from the server side.I can not able to understand the logic.Please help me !

Comment: Please see the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is your beginning stage so I answered but for later, please do some research and paste some code in which you are facing problems instead of directly asking logic. This will get you more answers. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are using MongoDB since you mentioned MEAN Stack. For implementing pagination, you can use the find, limit and skip functions.

Example: (pagesize is 10 records)

```
// Page 1
db.document.find().limit(10);
// Page 2
db.document.find().skip(10).limit(10);
// Page 3
db.document.find().skip(20).limit(10);
```

This is native to MongoDB however, this approach has a drawback as [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) states:

> The cursor.skip() method is often expensive because it requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection or index to get the offset or skip position before beginning to return results. As the offset (e.g. pageNumber above) increases, cursor.skip() will become slower and more CPU intensive. With larger collections, cursor.skip() may become IO bound.

You also can use any indexed field to achieve this (preferably **_id** field).